# Spring JPA throws Optional exception

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am writing a query. Query look like this

```
@Query("FROM Flight f WHERE f.goingTo.city =: goingTo and f.leavingFrom.city = :leavingFrom")
List<Flight> findByGoingToAndLeavingFrom(String goingTo,String leavingFrom);
```

when i try perform query, i get this error

---

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'flightManager' defined in file [C:\Users\msi\Desktop\spring\flight-search-api\flight-search-api\target\classes\com\example\flightsearchapi\service\impl\FlightManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'flightRepository' defined in com.example.flightsearchapi.repository.FlightRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.example.flightsearchapi.repository.FlightRepository.aaa(java.lang.String,java.lang.String); Reason: Using named parameters for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.flightsearchapi.repository.FlightRepository.aaa(java.lang.String,java.lang.String) but parameter 'Optional[goingTo]' not found in annotated query 'FROM Flight f WHERE f.goingTo.city =: goingTo and f.leavingFrom.city = :leavingFrom'
```

when i try with one param it works but nor work with 2 params.

Comment: `f.goingTo.city =: goingTo` doesn't look right in your query, should be `f.goingTo.city = :goingTo`. Please add your `Flight` and `GoingTo` classes to the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small typo in your Query, and also you are missing the @Param binding - so please correct it to:

```java
@Query("FROM Flight f WHERE f.goingTo.city = :goingTo and f.leavingFrom.city = :leavingFrom")
List<Flight> findByGoingToAndLeavingFrom(@Param('goingTo') String goingTo, @Param('leavingFrom') String leavingFrom);
```